# Jquery no se ejecuta

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentado poner un codigo jquery dentro de la etiqueta script pero no pasa nada:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Pruebas Javascript</title>
     
    </head>
    <body>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" scr="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

     <div align="center">  
      <h1>Formulario</h1>
     <form class="form-horizontal"> 
       Escribe tu nombre : <input id ="nombre" type="text"  name="nombre" > <br><br>
       Escribe tus apellidos : <input id ="apellidos" type="text" name="apellidos"><br><br>
       Escribe tu edad : <input id ="edad" type="text" name="edad"><br><br>
       <input type="button" id ="boton" name="boton" value = 'Aceptar' class="btn btn-primary" onclick="mostrar()">
     </form>
      </div>
    
      <script type="text/javascript">
    
          $("#boton").click( function(){
           alert("nada");
          });
     </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: ¿Y el error es?

Comment: Estoy intentando meter codigo jquery pero lo meto dentro de la etiqueta del script y no hace nada de nada

Comment: Primero, mete las etiquetas script y link en el head, eso no va dentro del body. Te diria que hagas lo mismo con el script del click. Usa document ready. Si todo esta en orden no veo que tenga que fallar.

Comment: He metido las etiquetas script y link en el head aunque solo utilizo la de boostrap y la de jquery , la otra no la utilizo porque estoy haciendo la funcion en el propio documento, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: @GDP Poner las etiquetas script en el head es malo. El navegador deja de procesar la pagina hasta que se descargue y procese el script, haciendo que la pagina se quede en blanco o que el usuario note un retraso

Comment: Entonces que hago? las dejo fuera del head o las meto dentro.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no, las etiquetas script tienen que ir en el head con el atributo async o defer para que no afecte al rendimiento.

Comment: @Lithorell tienes razon en eso: en el head con `async`/`defer` o al final del body. Es importante puntualizar la parte del `async`/`defer`

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses la última versión estable de `JQuery` (3.2.1), en tu código estás usando la 1.11.1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En la etiqueta script tienes `scr` cuando deberia de ser `src`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Pruebas Javascript</title>
     
    </head>
    <body>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

     <div align="center">  
      <h1>Formulario</h1>
     <form class="form-horizontal"> 
       Escribe tu nombre : <input id ="nombre" type="text"  name="nombre" > <br><br>
       Escribe tus apellidos : <input id ="apellidos" type="text" name="apellidos"><br><br>
       Escribe tu edad : <input id ="edad" type="text" name="edad"><br><br>
       <input type="button" id ="boton" name="boton" value = 'Aceptar' class="btn btn-primary" >
     </form>
      </div>
    
      <script type="text/javascript">
    
          $("#boton").click( function(){
           alert("nada");
          });
     </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: OH DIOS MIO GRACIAS, ERA UNA LETRA. GRACIAS

Comment: Por lo menos estamos seguros de que no te volvera a pasar :'D

Comment: Me fallaba esa letra y no cogia nada de la libreria de jquery

Comment: borra el llamado a la funcion "mostrar" por que te va a pinchar el codigo a futuro y vas a tener el mismo problema xD

Comment: einer, este tipo de fallos son "Errores tipograficos" y es motivo de cierre. Deberias comentarselo bajo la pregunta y reportarlo, en vez de publicar una respuesta. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren 3 soluciones:

1- Cambiar `$("#boton").click( function(){` por `$("#boton").click(function(e){`

2- Poner las funciones Jquery dentro de este codigo:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
      Poner tu codigo aqui
});
```

3-Deberias quitar el llamado `onclick="mostrar()"` Por 2 motivos:

- Podes estar sobre escribiendo la funcion "`Onclick`"
- Seguramente si haces click derecho en la pagina web que ejecuta tu
  codigo y pones "inspeccionar" vas a ver un boton rojo con una cruz,
  si clickeas en dicho boton te va a mostrar que tenes un error
  javascript, el error en teoria es que la funcion "`mostrar()`" no
  existe en tu codigo, entonces como no la encuentra pincha cualquier
  codigo javascript/jquery que tengas y no se ejecuta lo demas (aunque 
  este bien codificado)

Si no te sirve avisame y vemos otras opciones.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes en que en el onclick llamas a la función mostrar() que no existe.

`<input onclick=type="button" id ="boton" name="boton" value = 
     'Aceptar' class="btn btn-primary" onclick="mostrar()">`

la función mostrar() no esta definida
Para arrglarlo deberias de definirla de la siguiente manera:

```
$("#boton").click( function mostrar(){
            alert("nada");
        });
```